# How to make SVN trunk head the git master?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm creating a git repository from a SVN repository, and after running the necessary commands to fetch the SVN repo, I have the SVN `trunk` branch checked out as `master` in git. However, I don't want the entire `trunk` directory, but just the `head` directory to be the master in git. How can I set the master branch in git to point to the `trunk/head` directory in SVN?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that in your svn you have `<repo-base>/trunk/head` and you want the master of git to point to it? Then instead of using `-s/--stdlayout` you could explicitly say what you want you master to be:

`git svn clone <repo-base> --trunk=trunk/head --branches=...`